# Path to file in src directory

Tags: java, file, path

I am using a method that requires a string path to a file that is in my src directory structure in eclipse. Is the path to this file simply src\fileName.txt or is there a different way i should be getting this file as it doesnt seem to be working currently

Thanks

Comment: *"as it doesn't seem to be working currently"* - what does "it" refers to? Can you show us some code that you've tried?

Answer (score 3):

Run this and you will never forget how to remember.

File file = new File("sample.txt");
System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath());

Answer (score 0):

If you are following the maven standard directory structure, class files will be located relative to the classpath like so:

If you want `SomeClass.class`, you would access it by `com.mydomain.packageorappname.deeperpackage.SomeClass`. Is that what you are asking?